# Database on Raspberry pi

Tags: java, database, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project where the raspberry pi (model B) runs JAVA application to connect to and retrieve data from a Router.

What i want to know is the best approach or the best database that i should use to store that data retrieved from the router. Knowing that i will need to build another android application that should connect to that database (on the raspberry pi) and display that data.

So, what database that is compatible with the java application and the android application?

Also, later on i wish i could run the RPI as a server that enables me to connect to that database from anywhere.

Keeping in mind that:
I am new to Raspberry pi
New to Database

Comment: Do you want to run the database on your RPI ? I suggest to use a lightweight one, like H2 database, that can save you database into a file, like SQlite.

Comment: I am really new to RPI & new to databases in general ,
Is there another option than running the database on RPI? I don't have another components on the system , only the RPI , the router and later the connecting Android phone.

Comment: Well, after your edit, I think you need to turn your RPI into a sql database server. But I can't get what you really want to do in your project. Can you give more explanation ?

Comment: Ok, i have a kit (from nxp) which consists of:
sensors node : reads some climate data (temperature, humidity and so on )
a router: which is pre-programmed to connect to that node (they use ipv6)

then there is the raspberry pi.

What i did until now is:
Build a java application that runs on the RPI which connects to the router, get the values that the node reads and print it on the screen.

What i need to do next is to be able to connect to the RPI (through android phone for example) from anywhere (without direct connection to the router's local network) and get those values.

Comment: I guess this is your personal router. On this router you have :
- your RPI on which run you java app.
- your nxp kit which send the data to your RPI.

Here is what I'll do :
Define an open dns on your external IP. Thanks to this you can access your RPI from everywhere. And on the RPI, a local database in which your java app stock all the data provided by by the kit.

Comment: Ok, great.
But what is the best choice for the local database in that scenario?

Comment: You want to retrieve datas from everywhere, right ? You can use a database server (like mysql), so you connect directly on this server to get your data (suppose your future android app will connect directly to this db). Or you choose to access you data through you Java App, and in that case, you choose a file-based database like H2. Both H2 and MySQL provide a JDBC driver.

Comment: If you really need a relational DB, then SQLite or H2 are among the lightests. But for logging purposes, a regular file will do.

Comment: Great ,
@Maxime B  
Just to make sure that i am following.
Either mysql : the android app will directly access the database.

OR :
H2 : the android app will acces the data through the java app ..

Am i right?

If i am,  i don't really know which one i should use.
From your experience, which is better? (performance wise , maybe one will be heavy on the RPI) and which may be easier in implementation?

Thanks for your help

Comment: @MisterSmith , what do you mean by regular file will do ?

Comment: You are right, this is what I meant. Well, I guess it would be easier to access the MySQL Database through Android App. You'll just need to provide the location (the open dns) of the db. If your RPI is only used for this project, the performance won't really matter I guess. And @MisterSmith suggests to use a simple file, like a txt to save your datas.

Comment: Ok, i got it now.

Thank you all.
Thank you @MaximeB , you were very helpful.

Comment: @MaximeB.
One more thing please.
Until now, i worked as follows, i develop my java program using Eclipse IDE on windows 7. Then i export runnable jar file, copy it to the RPI and run from there.

Now that i will add mysql, how would i do it ?
Install mysql on the eclipse create the DB, install mysql on RPI and copy the file to RPI and run? or do i have to find a way to develop on the RPI itself ( install IDE on RPI) ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be on the [Raspberry Pi StackExchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), as it's mostly about the Raspberry Pi, and not a good fit for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer follows the previous comments. Let's say :

- You have your router. Connected to it you have PC (with IP address called IP1) and your RPI with IP2.
- On your RPI, I guess you have RaspBian. So with the package manager, you install mysql. You create your desired database and tables.
- When using eclipse to access your database for testing purpose, or explore all data, I think you need to provide the jdbc driver, and configure the url of the db. Because you are running eclipse on your pc and you want to access  the db hosted by the RPI, you should provide the IP2 address in the url.
- Because your Java app will run on RPI, you can set the url to "localhost". See the following link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
- So, to sum up, eclipse and java app both need a mysql jdbc driver, configured the right way.
- Later, you'll want to access your db through your android app. You'll need to configure your router with port forwarding, to access your db from outside. But this is out of topic. I let you search.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at [OrientDb](http://www.orientechnologies.com) is a NoSql Java graph-document db (you can chose) it support a lot of queries paradigm and an Sql dialect as well (you dont have the join), is fast, light, and support native rest query, i have tested it on raspberry pi (even in distributed multi-master mode on 2/3 raspberry node) and it perform well, the nice thing is that allow you to think in a different way, your data is presented like a java object an exposed you by rest paradigm in Json over http so you can think your client application on client side, using html 5 and jscript framework like angularJs for example (and you can 'deploy' your static resource direcly on the db that work like an extremly light application server)

Answer (score 0):

Almost All the Databases are Compatible with JAVA.And Hardly I belive that you will not have such privilege to choose Database while develop real time Application .

Java and Android Both are not different , both are same on a Pillar.There will be no problem because of using Database.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest SQLite as Android uses it natively and it does not need that much of resources as other DBMS like *SQL